# Asking for advice ("this or that" question)

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation

Sentence to translate:

> Would you recommend me to read a book or to go for a walk if I asked you for advice?

My attempt:

> Librum legere aut deambulationem ire me commendes si te ut consilium quaeram?

1. Is usage of ***legere*** and ***ire*** correct here?
2. I used present subjunctive for ***commendes*** and ***quaeram***, is that ok?
3. Is ***commendare*** correct word?
4. Does ***ut consilium*** mean ***for advice*** or should ***for*** be translatem using different word than ***ut***?
5. Would ***petere*** be better than ***quaerere*** here?
6. Are there mistakes not covered in previous questions? Do you have some other idea how to improve it?

Comment: The original question is "Shall I read a book, or shall I go for a walk." I think that is usually *"utrum, an ..."* + future indicative.  *Rogo, rogabo,* and *rogavi* will take the future subjunctive.  *Deambulo* (1st) is simpler than *deambulationem ire.*

Answer (score 3):

The original question is "Shall I read or shall I walk?" (future indicative)

> *"Legamne an ambulabo?"* **or** *"Utrum legam an ambulabo?"*

So, if your word for 'recommend' is in the present or future or past-perfect tense, then 'read' and 'go for a walk' will be *utrum ..an* with the future subjunctive. This is the compound verb composed of the future participle with the present subjunctive of *sum, esse.*

Comment: Something like: *Utrum librum lecturum sim an deambulaturum sim me commendes si te ut consilium quaeram*? Can first *sim* be deleted?

Comment: Great: you've sorted the indirect part. The next problem to solve is *commendes.* At present it is a statement. Somehow you have to turn it into a question.  'If I  asked, you would recommend,' into 'If I asked, would you recommend?'

Comment: Isn't it so that at least some questions in Latin can be formed simply by putting a question mark at the end of a statement?

Comment: If you say so. And in French all the time. But the enclitic interrogative particle would settle the matter.

Comment: I may be wrong about this. You mean ***-ne***? Isn't it used purely for yes/no questions? To clarify - here I want to ask what the answer would be if I asked the question and not whether the answer would be given if I asked.

Comment: So, are you interpreting it as  distancing or a polite circumlocution? "Would you mind if ...."  or "Would you care to tell me the way to,,,"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63108/discussion-between-przemyslawp-and-hugh).